# How is it possible to display results from a google apps script as text on an html page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script which Im using to read some properties of a Google site. I want to display the results of the script on the site in the script gadget box.
The results are just page names, so I think it can just be displayed as html text. Is there a way to do it?

for example if I use code a bit like this:

(Code.gs)

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('down')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function getnames {
var list_items = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/blablabla").getListItems();//got all list items here!
  Logger.log('Number of people on list: '+list_items.length+' Number of people pages: '+pages.length);

return list_items
}
```

(down.html)

```
????
```

and I would like to see the values in list_items displayed on the website page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a scriptlet in the down.html file:

### down.html

```
<?!= getnames(); ?>
```

You can't use `createHtmlOutputFromFile`, you must use `createTemplateFromFile`

### code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("down");

  return template
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the sandbox mode
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
};
```